# How to loop through different iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to put the `iframes` in a loop and have the next one waiting in queue while the first one loads, parses and renders. The second `iframe` only loads when the first one has been rendered successfully.

I've been using a `for loop` and tested `setTimeout`, and discovered that the timeout was only executed when the for-loop was over.

```js
var displayFrames = document.getElementById("displayframes");

for (var i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
  var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
  frame.src = "templates/" + filenames[i];
  frame.width = (window.innerWidth/3);
  frame.height = (window.innerHeight/2);
  displayFrames.appendChild(frame);
};
```

Could you suggest me any better way of handling this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe using the iframe `onload` event to trigger the next load?

```
var displayFrames = document.getElementById("displayframes");

var fileNameCounter = 0;

var loadIframe = function() {

    if(fileNameCounter >= filenames.length - 1)
        return;

    var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.src = "templates/" + filenames[fileNameCounter];
    frame.width = (window.innerWidth/3);
    frame.height = (window.innerHeight/2);
    displayFrames.appendChild(frame);

    fileNameCounter++;

    frame.onload = function() {
        loadIframe();
    }
}

loadIframe();
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck!